# Get element inside object of unknown depth JavaScript

Tags: javascript

say I have an object of unknown depth:

```js
let myObj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 10
    },
    b1: {
      c1: ...
      ...
    }
  },
  a1: {
    b: ...
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

and I want to get `c` and change the value.

If I knew the depth, this would be simple:

```js
myObj["a"]["b"]["c"] = 6;
```

However, in this case, I don't. I'm looking for an ES6 answer.
Thank you!

Comment: do you have to check every sub object ? like is there any other props like a in `myObj` ?

Comment: Hello, yes there are more sub-objects inside.

Comment: _"I'm looking for an ES6 answer"_ - Why?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: `array.reduce` but using that will only return a copied object, not the object itself. Also, I would like ES6 based on user preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively walk object and change value when key of 'c' is found.
One using some which returns on the first true result.
Other using a normal for-of loop.

```js
let myObj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 10
    }
  }
}

walk1 = node => Object.keys(node).some(k =>
  k === 'c' ? (node[k] = 'new value' || 1) : walk1(node[k]))

walk = node => {
  for (const k of Object.keys(node))
    if (k === 'c') {
      node[k] = 'new value'
      break
    }
  else walk(node[k])
}

walk1(myObj)
console.log(myObj)
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer! I will now test it out :)

Comment: Works perfectly! I'll mark this as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const flat = {};
let getChildren = ( parent ) => { 
Object.entries(parent).forEach(
    ([key, value]) =>  
    { if( typeof value == 'object' ){ 
        getChildren( value ) } 
      else { 
        flat[key] = value 
      }
    }) 
} 

getChildren( { a: {b: {c: {d: true}}} } );
```

this will lay out all children and their children to a flat object, given that all keys are unique

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! Is `flat` the object of unknown depth?

Comment: flat is end result. but yes, you can pass an object of an infinite depth to getChildren (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
let myObj = {
  a: {
     b: {
        c: 10
    }
  }
}
var count = 1;
function recur(obj, val){
if(Object.keys(obj) == val){
 console.log("Depth: " + count);
 return Object.values(obj)[0];
}
else {
 count++;
 return recur(Object.values(obj)[0], val);
}
}
console.log(recur(myObj, "c"));
```

If the current value is not within the first depth, return the function again and go deeper, and when the element is found, also output the depth in which it was found